# Probability using 2 urns

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $2$ urns:

- Urn #1 contains $6$ red balls and $5$ blue balls
- Urn #2 contains $1$ red ball, $3$ yellow balls and $8$ blue balls

A blue ball was drawn at random from one of the urns.

What are the chances that it was drawn from urn #1?

Am I on the right track with: $\frac{13}{23}-\frac{5}{11}\cdot\frac{8}{12}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the event of choosing urn #1.

Let $B$ denote the event of drawing a blue ball.

Then $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{5}{6+5}}{\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{5}{6+5}+\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{8}{1+3+8}}=\frac{15}{37}$